# Finding qgis2 folder to delete in ubuntu?

Tags: qgis, ubuntu

How can i find the qgis2 in qgis and where it is installed, i had one error on when qgis open this error will occurred "[ERROR] Can not make qgis.db private copy" some links told delete the folder qgis2, i can't find this folder.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: It will be in the User's Home directory. You need to give the user full rights over this directory.

Comment: You could post that as an answer, so that it helps future users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this folder is in hidden, so i went to option and click on the hidden files, and then now this folder is showing i try to delete one folder is not permit to delete the folder, i went inside the folder and change the permission, then it is deleted, Now this error is solved.